# How to have Outlook show as out of office but not clutter the Agenda list with appointments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is it possible to have an appointment every day outside working hours in MS Outlook that shows oneself as out of office but does not clutter up the agenda?

I would like to have my calendar show me as out of office at certain times but these shall not be shown in the Agenda List (neither Windows nor Android phone).

Answer (score 0):

As I know, if you create a appointment to let others see that you are out of office, the appointment must be shown in the calendar. There is no doubt about it. For more information about it, please refer to: [Add time away from the office to coworkers' Outlook calendars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-time-away-from-the-office-to-coworkers-outlook-calendars-69fe38aa-7b5f-4225-8b69-47f47092e65e).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.